# Write matrix for polynomial operator

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, operator-theory

For the question below, I am having trouble writing out the matrix for $T^k$.
 $P_3$ refers to the polynomial with degree up to $3$, and $p'$ refers to the first derivative of $p$

> Let $T:P_3(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow P_3(\mathbb{R})$ be the operator 
>   $$T:p\rightarrow p'-p''+p'''$$
>
> Write the matrix for  $T^k=T\circ\cdot\cdot\cdot\circ T$
>
> (with $k$ factors)  $\forall k=1,2,...,$ using the standard basis of $P_3$

Comment: Could you write out the matrix for $T$ atleast?

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* 
Write the matrix $A$ for $T$ by computing the action of $T$ on the elements of the standard basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$.
Then the matrix for $T^k$ is $A^k$.
As a sanity check, note that 
$T^k=0$ if $k\ge 4$.

You can also note that $T=D-D^2+D^3$, where $D(p)=p'$, and the matrices for $D,D^2,D^3$ are easy to compute.